# Adding new variable to an imputed dataset based on imputed values

Tags: r, r-mice

I wish to create a variable which is computed from values in two other variables from an imputed dataset and I was wondering if there's a way to achieve this?

e.g. if I wanted to create a new variable var_new to the nhanes dataset which I've run 16 m estimates on (in the mice package below), which was equal to the value of chl - bmi, is there a way to achieve this?

```
library(mice)
aux_vart <- mice::quickpred(
nhanes,
mincor = 0.1
)
imp <- mice::mice(nhanes, pred = aux_vart, m = 16, meth = "pmm")
```

I tried doing this with my original dataset and then imputing from that, but because the new variable is a function of the others it has resulted in nonconvergence of my models and wildly inaccurate parameter estimates on other models I've created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the full data sets and then add the column:

```
all_sets <- lapply(1:16, function(x) complete(imp, x))
final <- lapply(all_sets, function(x) cbind(x, var_new=x$chl - x$bmi))
```

Now `final` is a list containing all 16 data sets, final[[1]] to final[[16]], for example:

```
str(final[[1]])
# 'data.frame': 25 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ age    : num  1 2 1 3 1 3 1 1 2 2 ...
#  $ bmi    : num  28.7 22.7 22 22.7 20.4 25.5 22.5 30.1 22 26.3 ...
#  $ hyp    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
#  $ chl    : num  187 187 187 218 113 184 118 187 238 206 ...
#  $ var_new: num  158.3 164.3 165 195.3 92.6 ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still a little confused however (I'm still a novice at R so apologies!), I just have two further questions - by creating the full data sets does that refer to the steps I outlined above or something else? And what is the function you're specifying when adding the column? Thanks again.

Comment: You code used`mice()` to create 16  imputed values for each of the missing values in the data set. Use `str(imp)` to see the complicated list which is documented on the manual page at `?mids`. The `complete()` function takes that information to create complete data sets of the original data with the missing values replaced by the imputed values. The function takes each of the 16 imputed data sets and adds a `var_new` column. The `x` represents each of the data sets in `all_sets`.

Comment: Is there a way this code could be altered so it would output a `mids` object, not a list?

Comment: Look at the manual page for `mice`.  `imp <- mice(nhanes)` returns a `mids` object which the `complete()` function uses to generate data sets with imputed data.